# Tabla de articulos de carrito de venta con Observable en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicacion de ventas y quiero que al agregar un articulo sea por codigo de barra o por listado se actualice automaticamente la tabla de articulos de la compra.
Tengo en localStorage mi carrito con condicion de venta (contado cuenta corriente) y el nombre del cliente.
Ademas cree la interfaz de Concepto donde se guardarian los articulos:

carrito.service.ts;

```
export class carritoService {

  private carrito = new BehaviorSubject<Concepto[]>([]); //Definimos nuestro BehaviorSubject, este debe tener un valor inicial siempre
  public DataCarrito = this.carrito.asObservable(); //Tenemos un observable con el valor actual del BehaviourSubject

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {

  }
 
  getVenta(): Venta[] {
    const carrito = localStorage.getItem('carrito');
    if (carrito) {
      let carritoParse = JSON.parse(carrito);
      return carritoParse;
    } else{
      return [];
    }

  }
  addConceptos(c1: Concepto) {
    let recoveredData = localStorage.getItem('carrito')
    if (recoveredData == null) {
      //No tenemos nada guardado, por lo cual vamos a guardar el carrito
      this.actualizarCondicion("1");
    } else {
      //Tenemos algo, por lo cual vamos a añadir un nuevo concepto
      let data = JSON.parse(recoveredData);
      let conceptos = data.conceptos;
      //Asegurate que lo que guardes es realmente un array.
      let objIndex = conceptos.findIndex(((obj: { idArticulo: number; }) => obj.idArticulo == c1.idArticulo));
    //Si ya cargamos uno aumentamos su cantidad
        if(objIndex != -1)
        {
          conceptos[objIndex].cantidad += c1.cantidad;
        }
        //Si es el primer item de ese tipo lo agregamos derecho al carrito
        else {
          data.conceptos.push(c1);
          this.carrito.next(data);
        }  
        localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(data));
   
      }
    }
```

como veran usaria el metodo addConceptos, de hecho este funciona bien dado que en la consola del navegador observo los articulos y si agrego el mismo suma la cantidad del input.

en venta.component.ts tengo:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getclientes();
   let v1 = this.carrito.getVenta();
   let c1 = this.carrito.getCliente();
   this.carrito.DataCarrito.subscribe(carrito=>{
     this.lst=carrito;
   });
 
   this.ventaForm = this.formBuilder.group({

     condicionVenta:['',[
       Validators.required,
     ]],
     nombre_cliente:['',[
       Validators.required,
     ]],
   });
   
   this.ventaForm.patchValue(c1);
   this.ventaForm.patchValue(v1);
   
 }
```

Y por ultimo tengo la tabla en mi html. Necesito que al llamar a addconceptos se actualice la tabla es decir se muestre el articulo, en el boton del formulariode venta tengo:

```
  AgregarCodigo(){

   let codigoBarra = this.codigoBarraCtrl.value;
   let cantidad = this.cantidadCtrl.value;
   if (codigoBarra==null){
     alert("Campo Codigo Vacio");
   }
   if (cantidad==null){
    alert("Campo Cantidad Vacio");
   }
   if (codigoBarra && cantidad){
     let listadoArticulos = this.apiarticulo.getArticulos();
     
    let Concepto: Concepto = {id:1,idArticulo:120,nombreArticulo:"ACEITE",cantidad:cantidad,precio:10.36,subtotal:103.6,alicuotaIVA:21,baseImp:20};
    this.carrito.addConceptos(Concepto);
  }
   }
```

agrego venta.component.html:(mi table)

```
<table mat-table tabindex="4" fxFlex="100"  #table [dataSource]="this.carrito"  matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" matSortActive="nombreProducto" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
            
                <caption style="font-size: 20px;height: 4vh;border: 10px; color: rgb(54, 11, 211);"> DETALLE </caption>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="cantidad">
            
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cantidad</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="align-items: right;">{{element.cantidad}}</td>
            
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="nombreProducto">
            
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Descripcion</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="align-items: left;">{{element.nombreArticulo}}</td>
            
                </ng-container>
            
                <ng-container matColumnDef="precio">
            
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Precio</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.precio | currency:'$'}}</td>
            
                </ng-container>
               
                <ng-container matColumnDef="marca">
            
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Marca</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.nombre_marca}}</td>
            
                </ng-container>
              
                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            
                    <button mat-raised-button color="basic">Editar</button> |
                    <!-- <button (click)="delete(element)" mat-raised-button color="warn">Eliminar</button>-->
                  </td>
            
            
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:columnas"></tr>
            
              </table>
            </div>
              <mat-paginator #productsPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[50, 100,200]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Seleccionar pagina">
              </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: En la vista estas aplicando algo similar a esto ?-->`<div *ngIf='DataCarrito | async as data'>....generar tabla</div>`

Comment: Hola..no no tengo esa sentencia.

Comment: Puedes colgar el html para ver como lo bindeas?

Comment: listo ahi esta...lo demas esta bien?